# Getting a random Nullpointer when sending Image in chat QuickBlox?

Tags: android, chat, smack, quickblox

I am sending Image in my Chat App using QuickBlox . The scenario is when user sends a Image it first uploads to QuickBlox server and then send the message to other user. At send message I am getting this error randomly sometimes it doesnot show this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.LazyStringBuilder.length(LazyStringBuilder.java:72)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.XmlStringBuilder.length(XmlStringBuilder.java:212)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.LazyStringBuilder.length(LazyStringBuilder.java:72)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.XmlStringBuilder.length(XmlStringBuilder.java:212)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.LazyStringBuilder.length(LazyStringBuilder.java:72)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.LazyStringBuilder.toString(LazyStringBuilder.java:100)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.XmlStringBuilder.toString(XmlStringBuilder.java:227)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketWriter.writePackets(PacketWriter.java:163)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketWriter.access$000(PacketWriter.java:40)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketWriter$1.run(PacketWriter.java:77)
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you do it now, but there is the recommended way from QuickBlox team:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Send_and_receive_a_message_with_attachment

Use Content module to store your file attachments in chat

Comment: I was using similar approach and getting same error

Comment: I am using version 2.1

Comment: @NAVdroid can you create a separate ticket and post your code+ log

Comment: @IgorKhomenko I am getting this same issue but for normal message. Could u please help it.